# Как вернуть callback из класса в активность

Tags: android, socketio-client

Как при возникновение события, например CreateUser, в активности вывести результаты запроса

Код класса сокета

```
public class SocketClient  extends MultiDexApplication {
    private static final String TAG = "SocketClient";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/";

    private Socket mSocket;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MultiDex.install(this);

        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(URL);

            mSocket.on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "connect success");
                }

            }).on("SendUser", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    jsonObject = (JSONObject)args[0];

                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.get("result").toString());
                    } catch (JSONException js){
                        Log.e(TAG, js.toString());
                    }
                }

            }).on("CreateUser", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)args[0];
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.get("success").toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.get("message").toString());
                    } catch (JSONException jsonExc){
                        Log.e(TAG, jsonExc.toString());
                    }
                }
            }).on("SendMarker", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)args[0];

                    Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString());
                }
            }).on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect");
                }

            }).on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error connect");
                }
            }).on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connecting");
                }
            }).on(io.socket.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connect timeout");
                }
            });

            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    public Socket getmSocket(){
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

Код активности

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{
       private Socket mSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        SocketClient app = (SocketClient) getApplication();
        mSocket = app.getmSocket();

        if (mSocket.connected()){
            try {
                mSocket.emit("CreateUser", jsonObject.put("name", "user"));
            } catch (JSONException jsonExc){
                Log.e(TAG, jsonExc.toString());
            }
        }
       //Как-то обработать успешное создание пользователя и вывести сообщение
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерфейсом. Создайте его и передайте в класс, а в  активити реализуйте.

```
public class RequestDriveFolder {

private RequestDriveListener listener;

   private RequestDriveFolder(RequestDriveListener listener) {
       this.listener = listener;
}

 /*вызываем метод интерфейса. В него передаем данные*/
   publiс void requestFolder() 
       Data data = /*выполняем нужный запрос*/
                listener.resultOk(data);
     }
```

А вот сам интерфейс

```
 public interface RequestDriveListener {
      public void resultOk(Data data);
}
```

Реализация в активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RequestDriveListener{

   private RequestDriveFolder request;

   /*код*/
   private void request(){
     request = new RequestDriveFolder(this);

    }

   @Qverride
   public void resultOk(Data data){ 
      /*здесь получаем в активити данные и обрабатываем их*/
     }

}
```